# add data to an array within other arrays with a recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

I'm trying to add data to an element which inside it has an array, and that array others, and so on consecutively. I made a function to be able to traverse the entire element until finding the one I'm looking for by id, and then I add the new data to it and save it, but for some reason which I don't know, the data in the console is shown exactly as I expect, but in MongoDB, the data is not updated, and I'm out of ideas.

**CODE**

```
import Folder from "../models/Folder";
import SubFolder from "../models/SubFolder";
import File from "../models/File";

export const createFolder = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, mainFolder, folderId } = req.body;

    if (!mainFolder && !folderId) {
      const newFolder = new Folder({
        name,
        rute: "esto va a ser la ruta",
        files: [],
        subFolders: [],
      });

      const folderSaved = await newFolder.save();

      res.json({
        message: "Carpeta creada",
        folder: folderSaved,
      });
    } else {
      const newSubFolder = new SubFolder({
        name,
        rute: "esto va a ser la ruta",
        mainFolder,
        files: [],
        subFolders: [],
      });

      if (mainFolder === folderId) {
        const findMainFolder = await Folder.findOne({ _id: mainFolder });

        findMainFolder.subFolders.push(newSubFolder);

        await findMainFolder.save();

        res.json({
          message: "Carpeta creada",
          folder: findMainFolder,
        });
      } else {
        const findMainFolder = await Folder.findOne({ _id: mainFolder });

        async function procesarSubCarpetas(folder) {
          for (const subFolder of folder.subFolders) {
            let subFolderId = subFolder._id;

            if (subFolder.subFolders.length > 0) {
              await procesarSubCarpetas(subFolder);
            }

            if (subFolderId.toString() === folderId) {
              subFolder.subFolders.push(newSubFolder);
              return;
            }
          }
        }

        await procesarSubCarpetas(findMainFolder);

        await findMainFolder.save();

        res.json({
          message: "Carpeta creada",
          folder: findMainFolder,
        });
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al crear la carpeta:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Error al crear la carpeta" });
  }
};
```

I hope the data ends up in the database like this with the new data I'm trying to save.

**This is what the console returns to me, but it doesn't get saved.**

```
{
    "message": "Carpeta creada",
    "folder": {
        "_id": "65b4cc91cf802c9ab1974106",
        "name": "Test1",
        "rute": "esto va a ser la ruta",
        "files": [],
        "subFolders": [
            {
                "name": "Test1",
                "rute": "esto va a ser la ruta",
                "mainFolder": "65b4cc91cf802c9ab1974106",
                "files": [],
                "subFolders": [
                    {
                        "name": "NewFile",
                        "rute": "esto va a ser la ruta",
                        "mainFolder": "65b4cc91cf802c9ab1974106",
                        "files": [],
                        "subFolders": [],
                        "_id": "65b4cf2852b5e3e59f172003",
                        "date": "2024-01-27T09:38:48.464Z"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "65b4cc9dcf802c9ab1974108",
                "date": "2024-01-27T09:27:57.790Z"
            }
        ],
        "date": "2024-01-27T09:27:45.667Z"
    }
}
```

**This is what I want to add to the database within the SubFolders.**

```
{
 "name": "NewFile",
 "rute": "esto va a ser la ruta",
 "mainFolder": "65b4cc91cf802c9ab1974106",
 "files": [],
 "subFolders": [],
 "_id": "65b4cf2852b5e3e59f172003",
 "date": "2024-01-27T09:38:48.464Z"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working perfectly now. Seriously, I appreciate it. I was trying all night and I got stuck, and seriously, I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you're facing is related to `mongoose` not detecting the change you made to the nested `subFolders` array. Generally, when the nested object or array is modified in `mongoose`, you need to explicitly mark the path as modified to ensure that it gets saved when you call the `.save()` method. As a fix you will need to mark the path as modified by using the *[`.markModified()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#Document.prototype.markModified())* method before saving. Something like:

```js
// ...rest of your code
await procesarSubCarpetas(findMainFolder);

findMainFolder.markModified("subFolders"); // <--- Add this
await findMainFolder.save();

res.json({
  message: "Carpeta creada",
  folder: findMainFolder,
});
```